# How to shape array (sequence) to have arbitrary number of rows for a given number of columns

Tags: arrays, matrix, reshape, apl

Trivial example just to show the structure:

```apl
{190 10 ⍴⍵}{(⍳⍵)}1900
```

That "**190**" needs to be calculated as `⌈⍴⍵÷10` or if there is a symbol to say "pack all elements into an **R**-wide array and let it have as many rows as needed". The `{(⍳⍵)}1900` is just a stand in for an arbitrary code that will generate "the stream" of numbers and once they are slices into rows there would be more functions on the left side.

The problem of padding the last row is next so if someone has an idea for that as well (without exploding the size of the code) feel free to chime in. Or maybe it would be more compact to do that part first (if there is a simple way to slice it provided that the number is exact multiple of the desired raw width)? The row width may need to be variable (input, parameter) latter.

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated which APL you are using.

Comment: Your example is has unnecessary braces and parentheses: `190 10 ⍴ ⍳1900`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Let me know if any of the following code is unclear, as I will then elaborate on how it works.***

### Exact fit

My [Dyalog APL Extended](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended) repository contains [a cover function for `⍴`](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended/blob/master/Rho.dyalog) which does exactly this, but generalised to arrays of all ranks. It allows you to use `¯1` to indicate that a specific dimension's length should be automatically calculated to exactly fit the data. The code is as follows:

`⍵⍴⍨(|(×/⍴⍵)÷×/⍺)@(¯1=⊢)⍺` where `⍺` is the shape vector and `⍵` is the data. [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%AF1%2010%20%7B%u2375%u2374%u2368%28%7C%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%F7%D7/%u237A%29@%28%AF1%3D%u22A2%29%u237A%7D%20%u2373190&run)
 `(|(×/⍴⍵)÷×/⍺)` computes the length of the length marked with `¯1`
 `@(¯1=⊢)` amends `⍺` with this value at positions indicated by the mask `(¯1=⊢)⍺` (see [trains](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Introduction/Trains.htm))
 `⍵⍴⍨` reshapes `⍵` with that shape (rather than reshaping that to the shape `⍵`)

If you just need a matrix, the following will do the job in any APL you may be using:

`(((×/⍴⍵)÷⍺),⍺)⍴⍵` where `⍺` is the number of rows and `⍵` is the data. [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=10%20%7B%28%28%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%F7%u237A%29%2C%u237A%29%u2374%u2375%7D%20%u2373190&run)

### Padding

If you know you want to pad the last row (as opposed to erroring or omitting an incomplete trailing row), you basically have three options:

1. Recycle elements from the beginning of the data
2. Pad with the prototype element
3. Pad with a custom fill element

#### 1. Recycle elements from the beginning of the data

This one is easy, because that's what `⍴` does by default, so you just have to round up (`⌈`) the number of rows:

General Dyalog solution: `⍵⍴⍨(⌈|(×/⍴⍵)÷×/⍺)@(¯1=⊢)⍺` [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%AF1%2010%20%7B%u2375%u2374%u2368%28%u2308%7C%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%F7%D7/%u237A%29@%28%AF1%3D%u22A2%29%u237A%7D%20%u2373185&run)

Matrix only for all APLs: `((⌈(×/⍴⍵)÷⍺),⍺)⍴⍵` [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=10%20%7B%28%28%u2308%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%F7%u237A%29%2C%u237A%29%u2374%u2375%7D%20%u2373185&run)

#### 2. Pad with prototype element

For this we take the product of the computed shape vector and use that to "over" take (`↑`) elements from the ravelled (`,`) data before we use the shape vector to actually reshape:

General Dyalog solution: `((⌈|(×/⍴⍵)÷×/⍺)@(¯1=⊢)⍺){⍺⍴(×/⍺)↑,⍵}⍵` [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%AF1%2010%20%7B%28%28%u2308%7C%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%F7%D7/%u237A%29@%28%AF1%3D%u22A2%29%u237A%29%7B%u237A%u2374%28%D7/%u237A%29%u2191%2C%u2375%7D%u2375%7D%20%u2373185&run)

Marix only for all APLs: `((⌈(×/⍴⍵)÷⍺),⍺){⍺⍴(×/⍺)↑,⍵}⍵` [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=10%20%7B%28%28%u2308%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%F7%u237A%29%2C%u237A%29%7B%u237A%u2374%28%D7/%u237A%29%u2191%2C%u2375%7D%u2375%7D%20%u2373185&run)

#### 3. Pad with custom fill element

We can find how many fill elements (I'll use `¯3`) we need by subtracting the number of given data elements from the number needed. Then we concatenate (`,`) that many fill elements to the ravelled (`,`) data before reshaping:

General Dyalog solution: `((⌈|(×/⍴⍵)÷×/⍺)@(¯1=⊢)⍺){⍺⍴(,⍵),((×/⍺)-(×/⍴⍵))⍴¯3}⍵` [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%AF1%2010%20%7B%28%28%u2308%7C%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%F7%D7/%u237A%29@%28%AF1%3D%u22A2%29%u237A%29%7B%u237A%u2374%28%2C%u2375%29%2C%28%28%D7/%u237A%29-%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%29%u2374%AF3%7D%u2375%7D%20%u2373185&run)

Matrix only for all APLs: `((⌈(×/⍴⍵)÷⍺),⍺){⍺⍴(,⍵),((×/⍺)-(×/⍴⍵))⍴¯3}⍵` [Try it!](https://tryapl.org/?a=10%20%7B%28%28%u2308%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%F7%u237A%29%2C%u237A%29%7B%u237A%u2374%28%2C%u2375%29%2C%28%28%D7/%u237A%29-%28%D7/%u2374%u2375%29%29%u2374%AF3%7D%u2375%7D%20%u2373185&run)

Comment: OK, you you are basically saying that there's no "magic" (== without writing a sausage) way to get it. I was kind of hoping that, being "an IBM language" APL would have the concept of nullability and null tolerance (null==don't know, process as identity) and that there would be "some null" that would do what your ¯1 is doing - and fill with "nulls", OK defaults are better (that's post SQL concept, courtesy of C# - took a long time) :-). I was actually thinking in terms of "stream processing" - you don't know the length at all, just that they have to be packed into "k-tuples"

Comment: And since you offered :-) I do need some walkthrough for the 1st expression: What (¯1=⊢) does and where swap "cuts" on the right (I assume left cut is ⍵▶⍴) ? I have huge admiration for what Dyalog is doing but their docs are so lacking. I guess I need "APL for C++ devs, with shortcuts and term mappings for 3 'views' of the world' :-) including plain and higher functional :-). The problem with ⍨ : can't see directly where does it cut the expression (would have to write binding strengths I suppose) and there's no syntax to "mark it" (it can cut in the middle of a 'higher functional' currying).

Comment: @ZXX I've added a brief explanation. Is it enough? Btw, [binding strengths are fully documented](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Introduction/Binding%20Strength.htm). `⍨` is just a normal monadic operator like `¨`.